# UIAlertView strange corner display

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView within UIAlertView and now it shows some really ugly corners. I did enlarge the size of the alertview in willPresentAlertView().

```
#define ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH 750
#define ALERT_PADDING 20
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [[alertView class] description]);

        id thing;
        if ( [[[alertView class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIAlertTableView"]){ //change the alert view size
            NSLog(@"center: %f", alertView.center.x);

            int center=alertView.center.x-ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH/2;
            for (thing in alertView.subviews)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", [[thing class] description]);
                if([[[thing class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableView"])
                {
                    UIView* v=(UIView*)thing;
                    v.frame=CGRectMake(v.frame.origin.x+ALERT_PADDING, v.frame.origin.y, ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH-ALERT_PADDING*3, 250);
                }
                if([[[thing class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIAlertButton"])
                {
                    //UIView* v=(UIView*)thing;
                    //v.frame=CGRectMake(v.center.x, v.frame.origin.y, 100, v.frame.size.height-10);
                }
                if([[[thing class] description] isEqualToString:@"UILabel"])
                {
                    //UIView* v=(UIView*)thing;
                    //v.frame=CGRectMake(center-v.frame.size.width/2, v.frame.origin.y, v.frame.size.width, v.frame.size.height);
                }
            }
            alertView.frame=CGRectMake(center, alertView.frame.origin.y, ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH, 360);

        }        

    }
}
```

How this can be fixed? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has just stretched itself, rather than redrawn its contents. You would need to tell it it needs redrawing (`[alertView setNeedsDisplay]`), or set its content mode to redraw, so that the frame change triggers a redraw.

As an aside, this navigation of private view hierarchies is pretty fragile stuff. It wouldn't take much of a change in iOS for this to mysteriously stop working.

Comment: I tried both [alertView setNeedsDisplay] and             alertView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw but still I got the ugly corners.

Comment: I put "alertView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;" right after:
alertView.frame=CGRectMake(center, alertView.frame.origin.y, ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH, 360);

Comment: Well that wouldn't work as it would have already decided to redraw or not by that point. setNeedsDisplay should go after you change the frame, content mode should go before. But if that doesn't work, then perhaps the alert view can't be resized like this.